# how to pass laravel route parameter to vue

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-5.3

i m new to vue & i does lots of google but have not found any solution which is match to my current situation so don't know how i can pass route in vue component,
is there any way to pass this laravel route into vue template as below. my vue is location is resource/assets/js
here is code

```
               <template>
                   <a href={{route('/')}}></a>//i want to pass laravel route 
                                               //to view component this line 
                                                //throw error
               </template>
```

route(web.php) code

```
        Route::get('/' , function(){

                 Return view('homepage');
          });
```

i want to pass this url into vue component whose location (vue) is `resource/assets/js`

Comment: href={{route('/')}}: Interpolation inside attributes has been removed. Use v-bind or the colon shorthand instead. For example, instead of <div id="{{ val }}">, use <div :id="val">.  and if is use v-bind or :href={{route('/')}}  it throw error raw expression {{route('/')}}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with

```
<a :href="{{route('/')}}"> or <a v-bind:href="{{route('/')}}">
```

Comment: Assume that Vue js is running

Comment: both throw error here is description href={{route('/')}}: Interpolation inside attributes has been removed. Use v-bind or the colon shorthand instead. For example, instead of <div id="{{ val }}">, use <div :id="val">. and if is use v-bind or :href={{route('/')}} it throw error raw expression {{route('/')}}

Comment: i used this didn't get issue like this

Comment: can you show me example code note: my vue js file is in resource/asset/js

Comment: check this https://scotch.io/tutorials/implement-a-favoriting-feature-using-laravel-and-vue-js#toc-creating-the-favorite-component

Comment: no help :( this solution haven't match to my current condition

Answer (score 14):

You have to pass it as a prop inside your vue component.
They are two different steps.

> 1. Laravel spits out the compiled template
> 2. Vue parses the components and initializes them.

At step 2 you have to pass a prop with the route parsed at step 1

Something like this

```
<my-component route="{{ route('my-route') }}"></my-component>
```

Then within your component

```
<template>
    <a :href="route">CLICK HERE</a>
</template>

<script>
...
props: {
    route: { type: String, required: true }
}
...
</script>
```

Comment: You have to pass the prop in your component. Without seeing any code is hard to debug further than this.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use double curly brackets in your Vue components in relation to Blade. They are not functionally equivalent. Instead, pass the url as a string or bind it to a data attribute. The interpolation error you're seeing is a result of using the curly brackets and expecting them to be rendered vie the blade engine.

Your example is quite simple as `route('/')` is equivalent to just `/`.

```
// this is all you need to hit your defined route.
<a href="/">...</a>
```

Take a look at this package for generating client side routes and helpers in the Laravel fashion. Quite a handy package, I might add. I've used it myself in several larger projects.

https://github.com/aaronlord/laroute

As an aside, you mean the resources location `resource/assets/js`. Ultimately, that component will be located within your `public` directory if you use a build tool such as webpack, grunt, gulp, etc. so it's current location within the project directory isn't particularly relevant.

Answer (score 1):

OK, since none of above really worked for me, my solution is:

```
<my-component route="'{{ route('my-route') }}'"></my-component>
```

(This is an example of passing a `route` through component's props, but should work the same when used within `<a href=...`)

For me looks like Vue doesn't know that you're trying to pass a `string` so tries to evaluate your `route` as an expression. Quotes tell Vue that you want this to be a string.

Another solution, which works for passing almost everything (for instance whole objects) to Vue is encoding your variable using JSON format like:

```
<my-component route="{{ json_encode(route('my-route')) }}"></my-component>
```

Or Laravel 5.5 and up you can use  `@json` shortcut Blade directive for `json_encode`:

```
<my-component route='@json(route('my-route'))'></my-component>
```

Going further about JSON and objects - if Blade destroys your object data because of escaping the content you can use the following code:

```
<my-component route="{!! json_encode(route('my-route')) !!}"></my-component>
```

More on JSON and escaping data in Blade you can find [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade#displaying-data).